# Does MongoDB need to be restarted to reload a CRL?

Tags: mongodb

I'm running a MongoDB replica set with [TLS/SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/). I'm also using a CRL to block revoked certificates for clients. Relevant configuration of a replica set member follows.

```
net:
    ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: /opt/member.pem
        clusterFile: /opt/member.pem
        CAFile: /opt/ca.pem
        CRLFile: /opt/crl.pem

security:
    clusterAuthMode: x509
```

My question is: do I need to restart the `mongod` process each time I update the CRL file on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, the CRL file is not reloaded after initial MongoDB startup.

If you are actively making changes to the CRL file you will need to restart the `mongod` process(es) to ensure any changes take effect.

Comment: Thanks Stennie. I was using a CRL with a short lifespan as recommended by X.509 tutorials, so that became a concern. I reverted to using a CRL with longer validity since I have control over the entire replica set and I can issue a new CRL whenever I need to revoke a certificate, and do a rolling restart only in that situation. So this isn't much of a issue, actually.